# Reaching Catch block with res.status === 200

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm dispatching an action in a react app. Everything is working fine, I'm getting the response I'd expect, just User data and a JWT. My problem is it is still reaching the catch block even though the response is accurate and has a status of 200. Code is below.

```
export const submitNewUser = (user) => async (dispatch) => {
  // debugger;
  setLoading();
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${appConstants.serverRoot}/registerUser/user`,
      user,
      config
    );
    console.log("res", res);
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    // loadUser();
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_ERROR,
      payload: error,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: What it means is that your dispatch is failing. Maybe you can log the error in catch blog and see the exact error reported